# Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running (but I see it running)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm using passenger and nginx to host a rails app and unfortunately I'm receiving an error when I run passenger-status. I built a new server from a chef script I have and suspect I do have something misconfigured.

Versions:

- Phusion Passenger Enterprise 5.0.28
- nginx version: nginx/1.10.0

The error:

> ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure
>   that it is running, then the causes of this problem could be:
>
> 1. You customized the instance registry directory using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
>      passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger
>      Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument. If so,
>      please set the environment variable PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR to
>      that directory and run passenger-status again.
> 2. The instance directory has been removed by an operating system background service. Please set a different instance registry directory
>      using Apache's PassengerInstanceRegistryDir option, Nginx's
>      passenger_instance_registry_dir option, or Phusion Passenger
>      Standalone's --instance-registry-dir command line argument.

When I run `ps aux | grep Passenger` I get the following results:

> root     11877  0.0  0.1 431348  9368 ?        Ssl  Jun21   0:01
>   Passenger watchdog
>   root     11880  0.0  0.1 859564 11568 ?        Sl   Jun21   0:16
>   Passenger core
>   nobody   11885  0.0  0.1 439924 10232 ?        Sl   Jun21   0:03
>   Passenger ust-router

I didn't actually specify `passenger_instance_registry_dir` or use the `--nstance-registry-dir` command so I'm not sure what change to make.

My rails app does respond interestingly enough, although it does throw up an error page (and logs don't indicate why, which makes me think nginx is just serving it).

Comment: Exact same problem here, but with Apache. Can I ask if you ever fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem on apache. Installed from gem, no clue what went wrong.

The fix was to specify the PassengerInstanceRegistryDir as per: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengerinstanceregistrydir

I opted for non /tmp as there were some hints on the net that that could be the problem. Just have to create the directory you specify (eg in /var/run)

Comment: what file do you put it in?